# Qafih edition of Chovos Halvevavos Online

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, internet, mussar-ethics

Is R. Yosef Qafih's translation of the Chovos Halevavos available for free online (preferably as copyable text)?

Comment: care to explain yourself commentless downvoter?

Comment: No doubt. It's beyond useless to downvote a perfectly valid question that has numerous of like examples on this site. I make a motion that anyone who downvotes must leave a comments explaining it on this site. It should built into the functions of the forum. Just a thought. Kol tuv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Not at all.

But you can purchase the book from *Makhon Mosheh* in Israel. Their website is [www.net-sah.org](http://net-sah.org/content/10780)

If it is not online, then try calling or emailing them. Their site is currently being updated and is under a bit of minor construction.

I personally have it on my shelf. Is there a particular passage that you are looking for that I could post a picture of here? Let me know. I would be glad to help.

***UPDATE***:

Since you asked for the comments on Astrology, I have posted a picture of that portion below:

[image]

[image]

Enjoy!

Comment: I was looking for his comments on astrology. Thank you very much for the prompt answer and the offer for further assistance.

Comment: Do you have a reference specifically that I could go to for you? It would make it much easier. Thanks.

Comment: @mevaqesh - I added the section that you wanted. It is relatively short. Let me know if you need anything else. Kol tuv.

Comment: where is this in the sefer?

Comment: What exactly is he saying here regarding astrology?

Comment: This is in *ma'amar revi`i* and he is essentially responding to an accusation on the part of *al-khazari* that Jews believe in propitious times "like the astrologers." The *hhaver* responds that - in his opinion - it cannot be denied that the astral bodies have an influence on things below, however it is completely the realm of the Creator and no human can understand the depths of its complexities. However, he admits that should an authentic tradition of astrology be found in the tradition (which he apparently is not sure exists) then it is to be accepted while all other conjectures are to be

Comment: ...rejected since they are little more than empty guesses since they are without Divine assistance. He then ends with saying that the lotteries of the fortune-tellers and diviners would be more accurate than someone looking up and conjecturing. Anyhow, hope this helps. The section is about IV:8-11. Kol tuv.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but we are talking about the Chovos Halevavos, not the Kuzari, right?

Comment: Lol!! You are NOT ignorant at all! I am less than attentive! I don't know why I got the Kuzari in my head. Perhaps it was the astrology piece. SO so sorry. I also have the *Hhovoth* at home and will try to get it to you as soon as I can. Sheesh... :)

Comment: You still have the Kuzari pics up...